# Converting Ellipsoid Equation to Canonical Form Parameters

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, symmetric-matrices, quadrics, ellipsoids

Solving a least squares problem to try and get a best fit ellipsoid (or a general 4D conic section) to a cloud of data points such as the [database of nearby stars](https://github.com/astronexus/HYG-Database).

Can solve the linear equation portion, getting a result in the form of:

$a_0x^2 + a_1y^2 + a_2z^2 +a_3xy + a_4xz + a_5yz + a_6x + a_7y + a_8z + 1 = 0$

This question has similarities to: [Ellipsoid Equation: converting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182253/ellipsoid-equation-converting-from-implicit-form-to-explicit-matrix-form) so I tried to work through that first.

From there, hoping to get a parametric representation similar to [General Ellipse Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#General_ellipse)

where:
$x_c = $ ellipsoid center in x
$y_c = $ ellipsoid center in y
$z_c = $ ellipsoid center in y
$a = $ ellipsoid major axis length
$b = $ ellipsoid mid axis length
$c = $ ellipsoid minor axis length
$α = $ ellipsoid yaw
$β = $ ellipsoid pitch
$γ = $ ellipsoid roll
$θ = $ parameter, which ranges from 0 to 2π radians
$ϕ = $ parameter, which ranges from π/2 to -π/2 radians

### What I've Done

Based on the answers in the previous question, the process looks like convert to:

$ \mathbf x^T M \mathbf x + N \mathbf x + c = 0 $

with:

$\mathbf x =
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\\\
y \\\\
z
\end{pmatrix}
$

$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
A & D & E \\\\
D & B & F \\\\
E & F & C
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 & \frac{1}{2}a_3 & \frac{1}{2}a_4 \\\\
\frac{1}{2}a_3 & a_1 & \frac{1}{2}a_5 \\\\
\frac{1}{2}a_4 & \frac{1}{2}a_5 & a_2
\end{pmatrix}
$

$N =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_6 \\\\
a_7 \\\\
a_8
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
G \\\\
H \\\\
I
\end{pmatrix}
$

Then, can find the center:

$\mathbf x_c =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_c \\\\
y_c \\\\
z_c
\end{pmatrix}
$

Using: $\mathbf x_c = − \frac{1}{2}M^{-1}N$

Doing so, I get:

$\mathbf x_c =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_c \\\\
y_c \\\\
z_c
\end{pmatrix} = - \frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{G\left(BC-F^2\right)+H\left(EF-CD\right)+I\left(DF-BE\right)}{2DEF+C\left(BA-D^2\right)-AF^2-BE^2} \\\\
\frac{G\left(EF-CD\right)+H\left(CA-E^2\right)+I\left(DE-AF\right)}{2DEF+C\left(BA-D^2\right)-AF^2-BE^2} \\\\
\frac{G\left(DF-BE\right)+H\left(DE-AF\right)+I\left(BA-D^2\right)}{2DEF+C\left(BA-D^2\right)-AF^2-BE^2}
\end{pmatrix}$

From @Jan-Magnus Økland answer in the same thread, and this [Wikipedia on Ellipsoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#As_a_quadric) it looks like a,b,c are then the reciprocals of the eigenvalues of M found with $M=R D R^T$ where:

$D = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda _1 & 0 & 0 \\\\
0 & \lambda _2 & 0 \\\\
0 & 0 & \lambda _3
\end{bmatrix}
$

$a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{- \lambda _1}}$

$b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{- \lambda _2}}$

$c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{- \lambda _3}}$

And then the rotation matrix:
$R = R_z(\alpha) \, R_y(\beta) \, R_x(\gamma) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\alpha\cos\beta &
\cos\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma - \sin\alpha\cos\gamma &
\cos\alpha\sin\beta\cos\gamma + \sin\alpha\sin\gamma \\\\
\sin\alpha\cos\beta &
\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma + \cos\alpha\cos\gamma &
\sin\alpha\sin\beta\cos\gamma - \cos\alpha\sin\gamma \\\\
-\sin\beta & \cos\beta\sin\gamma & \cos\beta\cos\gamma
\end{bmatrix}
$

is made from the eigenvectors of M, using the same $M=R D R^T$

So then:

$β = - \sin^{-1}(R _{20})$

Then with: $\frac{R _{21}}{R _{22}} = tan(γ)$

$γ = tan^{-1}( \frac{R _{21}}{ R _{22}} ) = atan2(\frac{R _{21}}{cos(β)}, \frac{R _{22}}{cos(β)}) = atan2(\frac{R _{21}}{\sqrt{1-R _{20}^2}}, \frac{R _{22}}{\sqrt{1-R _{20}^2}})$

and then with: $\frac{R _{10}}{R _{00}} = tan(α)$

$α = tan^{-1}( \frac{R _{10}}{ R _{00}} ) = atan2(\frac{R _{10}}{cos(β)}, \frac{R _{00}}{cos(β)}) = atan2(\frac{R _{10}}{\sqrt{1-R _{20}^2}}, \frac{R _{00}}{\sqrt{1-R _{20}^2}})$

All the rotation matrix stuff taken from [G. Slabaugh Paper on Computing Euler Angles](http://eecs.qmul.ac.uk/%7Egslabaugh/publications/euler.pdf)

### Actual Questions

- Are a,b,c really just the reciprocal of the eigenvalues of M?

  - Does this work for non-spherical ellipsoids (think that's a hyper-conic section? If it was 2D they would be hyperbola or parabola)
  - From the [previously quoted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4182253/ellipsoid-equation-converting-from-implicit-form-to-explicit-matrix-form) it looks like @Jan-Magnus Økland and @Amazing Dell Computers are proposing somewhat different methods.  Background is engineering, so feel like I'm way out of my depth of math-fu on this.
  - <strike>@Amazing Dell Computers did something with dividing by $(r_0^T A r_0 - c)$, however that seems like it would either result in dividing a 3x3 by an nxn matrix or getting a M' for every single data point?</strike>
- If the 3x3 matrix is symmetric, is there a general decomposition for the eigenvalues (as long as its not defective)? (IE: can be written as an equation and does not just involve computing numbers?)

  - I'd prefer a result I could write in terms A,B,C,D,E,F

    - Something that looks like the ellipse results.
    - Just from the center calculation, there's several optimizations obvious.  Hoping other terms might simplify.
  - Especially since decomposition directly results in rotation matrices made of cos() sin(), seems like there ought to be some relation for $M=R D R^T$
- Are there any really obvious errors I've missed, or bad calculation assumptions?

### Edit 12/29/2022

After a bit of trial and tribulations, appear to have a functioning result.

- Notably, dividing through by $(r_0^T A r_0 - c)$ did end up necessary, as otherwise the center offset is not taken into account correctly.
- Also, a, b, c appears to require Abs( eigenvalue )

$a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lvert \lambda _1 \rvert}}$

$b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lvert \lambda _2 \rvert}}$

$c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lvert \lambda _3 \rvert}}$

Otherwise, results like shown below, with obvious best fit spheres result in mixed sign eigenvalues.
[image: SphereFitExample]
Also, the original result I was trying to get, best fit sphere to stars within 100 LY of Earth
[image: SphereFit100LYStars]

Comment: Check out principle components analysis. It works for any number of dimensions. The principle component vectors are the axes of the ellipsoid. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis

Answer (score 1):

The equation for an ellipsoid in canonical form is given by:

$$\frac{(x-xc)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-yc)^2}{b^2}+\frac{(z-zc)^2}{c^2}=1$$

where $(xc,yc,zc)$ is the center of the ellipsoid, $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the lengths of the semi-axes, and the angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ determine the orientation of the ellipsoid. The angles are defined by:

$$\alpha=\arctan\left(\frac{D}{E}\right)$$
$$\beta=\arctan\left(\frac{F}{\sqrt{E^2+D^2}}\right)$$
$$\gamma=\arctan\left(\frac{E}{D}\right)$$

where the constants $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$, $G$, $H$, $I$, and $J$ are defined as follows:

$$A=\frac{a_0}{(a_3/2)^2+(a_4/2)^2+(a_5/2)^2}$$
$$B=\frac{a_1}{(a_3/2)^2+(a_4/2)^2+(a_5/2)^2}$$
$$C=\frac{a_2}{(a_3/2)^2+(a_4/2)^2+(a_5/2)^2}$$
$$D=\frac{a_3}{(a_3/2)^2+(a_4/2)^2+(a_5/2)^2}$$

$$E=\frac{a_4}{(a_3/2)^2+(a_4/2)^2+(a_5/2)^2}$$
$$F=\frac{a_5}{(a_3/2)^2+(a_4/2)^2+(a_5/2)^2}$$
$$G=\frac{a_6}{(a_3/2)^2+(a_4/2)^2+(a_5/2)^2}$$
$$H=\frac{a_7}{(a_3/2)^2+(a_4/2)^2+(a_5/2)^2}$$
$$I=\frac{a_8}{(a_3/2)^2+(a_4/2)^2+(a_5/2)^2}$$
$$J=\frac{1}{(a_3/2)^2+(a_4/2)^2+(a_5/2)^2}$$

The center of the ellipsoid $(xc,yc,zc)$ is given by:

$$xc=-\frac{G}{2A}$$
$$yc=-\frac{H}{2B}$$
$$zc=-\frac{I}{2C}$$

The lengths of the semi-axes are given by:

$$a=\sqrt{-\frac{AH^2+BG^2-2GHD}{4AB-D^2}}$$

$$b=\sqrt{-\frac{AH^2+BG^2-2GHD}{4AB-D^2}}$$

$$c=\sqrt{-\frac{AI^2+CG^2-2GIH}{4AC-E^2}}$$

Note that these formulas assume that $A$, $B$, and $C$ are all positive. If any of these coefficients are negative, the corresponding axis length and angle will need to be negated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ive since edited my answer to be more readable,

Comment: Thank you for the answer @James.  Is there a paper, or reference for these?  Like I mentioned in the question, engineer feeling rather out of my math depth, so trying to understand the process and mathematics involved, ultimately allowing me to work through them and feel like I have a grasp of "why" the results are the way they are.

Comment: Also interesting, this implies there's a generalized 3x3 eigenvalue decomposition for symmetric matrices? Something I haven't seen written about.  A link to that would be pretty neat if it exists as a reference.